# Right way to cancel rabbitmq consuming with pika

Tags: python, rabbitmq, amqp, pika

I want to implement rpc client using rabbitmq. My code primarily looks like

```
def start(self):
    while True:
        self.channel.basic_consume(self.on_delivery)
 ...
 client.start() // blocking call
```

What is right way to stop this client ?
Now I make `channel.basic_cancel(self.on_cancel, self.consumer_tag)` from another thread. However [pika faq says](http://pika.readthedocs.org/en/latest/faq.html) `It is not safe to share one Pika connection across threads.`

What is preferred way to cancel consuming ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long as you create *one* connection *per* thread, you should be fine.

eandersson created an example of this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17225409/1272394).

Answer (score 0):

If you want use `basic_cancel` see [this gist](https://gist.github.com/swinton/5438483)

you can see code briefly like below:

```py
def callback(ct, ch, method, properties, body):
   ...
   ch.basic_cancel(consumer_tag=ct, nowait=False) # WARNING no such parameter `nowait` please remove from method call
   ...

...
consumer_tag = uuid.uuid1().hex
channel.basic_consume(partial(callback, consumer_tag),
                              queue=queue_name,
                              consumer_tag=consumer_tag) # add consumer_tag
...
```

in *pika@1.3.3* there is no such parameter named `nowait`, so you just remove it from method call.