# Multiple consumer in rabbitmq for multiple queue

Tags: python, rabbitmq, pika, python-pika

I have 2 queues, say q1 and q2, which corresponds to e1 and e2 exchanges with binding key b1 and b2. I want to run consumer functions in parallel, say c1 and c2 which will listen to q1 and q2 respectively. I tried the following way:

```
def c1():
    connection = pika.BlockingConnection(pika.ConnectionParameters(host=constants.rmqHostIp))
    channel = connection.channel()
    channel.exchange_declare(exchange='e1', durable='true',
                         type='topic')
    result = channel.queue_declare(durable='false', queue='q1')
    queue_name = result.method.queue
    binding_key = "b1"
    channel.queue_bind(exchange='e1',
                       queue=queue_name,
                       routing_key=binding_key)
    channel.basic_consume(callback,queue=queue_name,no_ack=False)
    channel.start_consuming()

def c2():
    connection = pika.BlockingConnection(pika.ConnectionParameters(host=constants.rmqHostIp))
    channel = connection.channel()
    channel.exchange_declare(exchange='e2', durable='true',
                         type='topic')
    result = channel.queue_declare(durable='false', queue='q2')
    queue_name = result.method.queue
    binding_key = "b2"
    channel.queue_bind(exchange=e1,
                       queue=queue_name,
                       routing_key=binding_key)
    channel.basic_consume(callback,queue=queue_name,no_ack=False)
    channel.start_consuming()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    c1()
    c2()
```

However, it is only listening to c1 function and c2 function, it is not getting executed. How can I run the both functions?
Thanks in advance.

EDIT: I have method c1 and c1 in 2 different module(file)

Comment: You should be using python threading module or some alternative to blocking connection.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Consume multiple queues in python / pika](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24510310/consume-multiple-queues-in-python-pika)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In order to run both functions simultaneously some multi threading method needs to be in order. Please have a look [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html) for some python examples.

Here is your code modified with the Process class. It can also use thread or run it explicitly from the OS.

```
import pika
from multiprocessing import Process


def callback():
    print 'callback got data'


class c1():
    def __init__(self):
        self.connection = pika.BlockingConnection(pika.ConnectionParameters('localhost'))
        self.channel = self.connection.channel()
        self.channel.exchange_declare(exchange='e1', durable='true', type='topic')
        result = self.channel.queue_declare(durable='false', queue='q1')
        queue_name = result.method.queue
        binding_key = "b1"
        self.channel.queue_bind(exchange='e1', queue=queue_name, routing_key=binding_key)
        self.channel.basic_consume(callback,queue=queue_name,no_ack=False)

    def run(self):
        self.channel.start_consuming()


class c2():
    def __init__(self):
        self.connection = pika.BlockingConnection(pika.ConnectionParameters('localhost'))
        self.channel = self.connection.channel()
        self.channel.exchange_declare(exchange='e2', durable='true', type='topic')
        result = self.channel.queue_declare(durable='false', queue='q2')
        queue_name = result.method.queue
        binding_key = "b2"
        self.channel.queue_bind(exchange='e1', queue=queue_name, routing_key=binding_key)

        self.channel.basic_consume(callback,queue=queue_name,no_ack=False)

    def run(self):
        self.channel.start_consuming()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    subscriber_list = []
    subscriber_list.append(c1())
    subscriber_list.append(c2())

    # execute
    process_list = []
    for sub in subscriber_list:
        process = Process(target=sub.run)
        process.start()
        process_list.append(process)

    # wait for all process to finish
    for process in process_list:
        process.join()
```

Answer (score 0):

#### You can receive messages from multiple queues using one connection and one channel. The `pika` python module has built in test code that tests with one blocking connection and one channel (FYI this [test code is from 2015](https://github.com/pika/pika/commit/94f86187bf8cbd6cdc18a52f17c564fbb2c78169)).

Here is the pika python module test code that tests getting messages from  multiple queues using one blocking connection and one channel: https://github.com/pika/pika/blob/1.3.0/tests/acceptance/blocking_adapter_test.py#L2072-L2172 .

p.s. For my own stubborn reasons i also wrote similar code that used one blocking connection and one channel and two queues and verified this to work also.