# Python tutorial code from RabbitMQ failing to run

Tags: python, rabbitmq

**Edit:** I had the wrong version of the pika package installed on my device. It works fine after I updated from pip.

I just started learning the usage of RabbitMQ (using Python) by following their [tutorial](https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-one-python.html). The `send.py` code works works fine but when I try to run `receive.py`, I see this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "receive.py", line 15, in <module>
    no_ack=True)
TypeError: basic_consume() got multiple values for keyword argument 'queue'
```

Here's the code inside `receive.py`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import pika

connection = pika.BlockingConnection(pika.ConnectionParameters(host='localhost'))
channel = connection.channel()


channel.queue_declare(queue='hello')

def callback(ch, method, properties, body):
    print(" [x] Received %r" % body)

channel.basic_consume(callback,
                      queue='hello',
                      no_ack=True)

print(' [*] Waiting for messages. To exit press CTRL+C')
channel.start_consuming()
```

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Comment: can you show your code ? where you use basic_consume()

Comment: Yeah, added. I thought I didn't need to since it was on the website. Sorry about that.

Comment: @sudhavna i run your code and it works

Comment: Your traceback claims the file is called `receieve.py`, you claim its called `receive.py` ... sure you're editing the right file?

Comment: Oops. Made a spelling error naming my file. But yeah, I _am_ editing the same file.

Comment: @zimdero okay that's weird

Comment: Your code works for me, too.

Comment: Okay, I had one of my colleagues try and it worked for him as well. This is extremely strange.

Comment: I'll write a complete setup as an tutorial right now.

Answer (score 31):

You probably don't need it anymore, but I had exactly the same problem as You and this is what I figured out.

For me it turned out that RabbitMQ documentation must've been using a different version of pika. I found out that in pika 1.0.0 basic_consume function has different order of arguments. This is how it looks on my machine:

```
    def basic_consume(self,
                  queue,
                  on_message_callback,
                  auto_ack=False,
                  exclusive=False,
                  consumer_tag=None,
                  arguments=None):
```

Once I changed the order of arguments passed, or added keyword 'on_message_callback=callback' it all worked. I hope it helps!

Answer (score 21):

just change

```
channel.basic_consume(callback, queue='hello', no_ack=True)
```

to

```
channel.basic_consume('hello', callback, auto_ack=True)
```

Comment: they simply swapped the args between Pika 0.9.x and 1.0.x also naming all args works:
`channel.basic_consume(on_message_callback=callback, queue='hello', no_ack=True)`

Comment: To get the same behaviour as `no_ack=True`, I think you need `auto_ack=False`.

Answer (score 5):

I can't reproduce your error, but I want to be as concise as possible, when trying to.

At first I set up a rabbitmq server [as docker container](https://hub.docker.com/_/rabbitmq/) on my computer, not to pollute my system:

```
$ docker run -d --hostname localhost --name some-rabbit rabbitmq:3
```

Then I use inspect to find about the IPAddress my rabbitmq container is running actually:

```
$ docker inspect some-rabbit --format='{{range .NetworkSettings.Networks}}{{.IPAddress}}{{end}}'
172.17.0.2
```

Next I use [pipenv](https://pipenv.kennethreitz.org/) to create a virtual environment in python3 that contains at least pika and dependencies to follow the example:

```
$ mkdir example && cd example && pipenv --three install pika
Creating a virtualenv for this project…
Using /usr/bin/python3 (3.6.5) to create virtualenv…
```

Note, that you can also use python 2.7 here if you say `pipenv --two` when installing pika.

Then jump into the environment using pipenv shell:

```
~/example$ pipenv shell
Spawning environment shell (/bin/bash). Use 'exit' to leave.
```

There I create the two files `send.py` and `receive.py` as proposed by the [example documentation of pika](https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-one-python.html), but I'll replace the `localhost` by the docker containers IP from above:

```
$ cat send.py 
#!/usr/bin/env python 
import pika

connection = pika.BlockingConnection(pika.ConnectionParameters(host='172.17.0.2'))
channel = connection.channel()


channel.queue_declare(queue='hello')

channel.basic_publish(exchange='',
                      routing_key='hello',
                      body='Hello World!')
print(" [x] Sent 'Hello World!'")
connection.close()
```

And `receive.py`:

```
$ cat receive.py
#!/usr/bin/env python
import pika

connection = pika.BlockingConnection(pika.ConnectionParameters(host='172.17.0.2'))
channel = connection.channel()


channel.queue_declare(queue='hello')

def callback(ch, method, properties, body):
    print(" [x] Received %r" % body)

channel.basic_consume(callback,
                      queue='hello',
                      no_ack=True)

print(' [*] Waiting for messages. To exit press CTRL+C')
channel.start_consuming()
```

Having receive.py running in one terminal and running send.py in another works as expected:

```
 $ python receive.py 
 [*] Waiting for messages. To exit press CTRL+C

 $ python send.py
 [x] Sent 'Hello World!'

 $ python receive.py 
 [*] Waiting for messages. To exit press CTRL+C
 [x] Received b'Hello World!
```

HTH,
f3rdy

Comment: Thanks for the very well written tutorial. Turns out I had the wrong version of Pika installed.

Answer (score 1):

I got the same issue on Ubuntu 18.04 with the in-stock python-pika package version 0.11.0-1, after I remove the in-stock version and installed a newer version pika (1.0.1) by pip, this issue disappeared.

Answer (score 0):

just change

```
channel.basic_consume(callback, queue='hello', no_ack=True)
```

to

```
channel.basic_consume(queue='hello', callback, no_ack=True)
```

because i found the code in lib is.

Comment: def basic_consume(self,
                      queue,
                      on_message_callback,
                      auto_ack=False,
                      exclusive=False,
                      consumer_tag=None,
                      arguments=None):

Comment: This doesn't work. The second like should be without `queue=` and `no_ack` should be `auto_ack`, thus, the correct line is: `channel.basic_consume('hello', callback, auto_ack=True)`

Answer (score 0):

This code might help:

```
channel.basic_consume(on_message_callback=callback, queue='hello')
```

or

```
channel.basic_consume(on_message_callback=callback, queue='hello', auto_ack=True)
```